# Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, https, web-config

My WebConfig:

```xml
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="SecureBasicRest">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="svcBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="svcEndpoint">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
      <enableWebScript/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="SvcContract.Authenticate" behaviorConfiguration="svcBehavior">
    <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecureBasicRest"
              behaviorConfiguration="svcEndpoint" name="webHttp"
              contract="SvcContract.Authenticate" />
  </service>
</services>
```

I have to make this work with
https://localhost:6188/Authenticate/Login?username=user&password=pass&ip=127.0.0.1

Comment: Have you mapped a service certificate on IIS for the website under which this application is hosted? Do you have the https binding enabled on the website?

Comment: Did you get final solution?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Change

```
<serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
```

to

```
<serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
```

You're telling WCF to use https for the metadata endpoint and I see that your'e exposing your service on http, and then you get the error in the title.

You also have to set `<security mode="None" />` if you want to use HTTP as your URL suggests.

Comment: I'm sorry for typo error, I really have to make it using https. Your answer works great for http, but how could it work for https? Thanks

Comment: Have you set up ssl bindings for your site in IIS?

Comment: Just to make it clear, are you running your service in visual studio's web server? It does not support SSL. If you need to do development with SSL use IIS Express.

Answer (score 30):

You would need to enable https binding on server side. IISExpress in this case. Select Properties on website project in solution explorer (not double click). In the properties pane then you need to enable SSL.

Comment: If you have a version of Visual Studio that doesn't show these properties when you right click, select the project and press F4.

Comment: You saved my day... Thanks mate!

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by adding https binding in my IIS websites and adding 443 SSL port and selecting a self signed certificate in binding.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To make it work you have to replace a run this line of code 
`serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>` http instead of https
and `security mode="None" />`

Answer (score 0):

In the endpoint tag you need to include the property address=""

`<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecureBasicRest" behaviorConfiguration="svcEndpoint"  name="webHttp" contract="SvcContract.Authenticate" />`

Answer (score 0):

In our case; I had to remove the "<baseAddressPrefixFilters" from the config file.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33314615)